# TFS/VSTS Release Agent best practices

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We are wondering about the best setup to release our applications:

1- A Dedicated server that will run one or multiple agents to release on one or multiple servers for different environment (Staging & Production).

**or**

2- One agent on each server (Staging & Production) that will directly release on the server.

=> I think it's not a best practices to install the agent on the production server but it can make simultaneous deployment on multiple server easier and in that case we don't need a dedicated server for releasing.

The builds are done by a dedicated server.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion there is really not necessarily a best practice in doing it one way or other way, but some other considerations, like security and deployment duration, among others.

From a security point of view, you have to consider that your agent's machine must have access to the TFS/VSTS account. So if it is an internal TFS server you will not have this issue. If it is VSTS, then you will have to consider this with your infrastructure guys.

If you will have one dedicated server for deployment, all the work will have to be done remotely on target servers and for that VSTS tasks uses WinRM, which will have to be enabled on each target machine. These tasks require administrative access to your server and for that reason they will ask you to enter an administrator account/password on the task configuration interface (web browser). This another point that will better discuss with IT, because you will be storing sensitive information on your TFS/VSTS system.

When you have the agent installed on all servers, you will be doing local deployments after the artifacts have being downloaded. This is faster than deploying them remotely with WinRM (self experienced it). But you will have to get access to your TFS/VSTS account on every agent machine.

Personally I prefer to go with the agent installed on each server, but you have to consider your own environment characteristics.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback Rodrigo! :)